# How to query for Realm objects related to multiple other Realm objects in Realm Java

Tags: android, realm

When I try to query for object relationship by passing the object in the `equalTo` query, the IDE complains that the comparison cannot be made. What is the correct way to query for Realm objects related to each other? My relationships are set up like this:

```
public class Workout extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    @Required
    private String name;
    public RealmList<Set> sets;
    public RealmList<Exercise> exercises;
    private Date date;

public class Set extends RealmObject implements Parcelable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    @Required
    private Date date;
    private Workout workout;
    private Exercise exercise;
    private int reps;
    private float weight;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have one object (a `Workout`) which has one or more `sets` and `exercises` related to it. A `set` is related to an `exercise` and a `workout`. To count the sets of a given exercise within a given workout, I need to find all sets which are related to the `exercise` *and* the `workout`. This can be accomplished by using any unique field for the desired objects and a dot access notation.

For example:

```
results = realm.where(Set.class).equalTo("workout.id", this.getId())
                .equalTo("exercise.id", exercise.getId())
                .findAll();
```

Here I use the UUID created for each of the objects and compare that rather than the object itself. This works until abstract direct object comparison is implemented in Realm.